# JAVA floating point operations

Tags: java

I'm doing a lot of floating point operations in my application, and I'm aware that floating point operations are not 100% accurate which is fine but when it comes to printing the result I have yet to find a way to format it properly.

for example

0.1 + 0.1 = 0.19999999999999999999999

Math.sin(Math.PI) = 1.2246E16 instead of 0

and stuff like 1.000000000000000001

I'm looking for a general way to take those results and get the proper rounded value (in a String form)

so that
0.1 + 0.1 = 0.19999999999999999999999 -> 0.2  this one requires rounding up

Math.sin(Math.PI) = 1.2246E16 -> 0

and stuff like 1.000000000000000001 -> 1     ; while this one requires rounding down

I'd also like to avoid losing data in cases like when the result is
1.1234567891234567 or 1.33333333333333 in those cases the result should remain the same.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Not possible. How would the program know whether it should round `0.1999999999999` (because it was the result of `0.1 + 0.1`) or not (because it was the result of `0.2 - 0.000000000001`?

Comment: `System.out.println(0.1+0.1)` produces "0.2", incidentally

Comment: Yep, fair enough - best to use an example in your question that actually shows the problem though ;-)

Comment: I think you mean `1.2246E-16` rather than `1.2246E16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid using formatting, you can round the result to a fixed precision before printing it and use the fact that Java will do a small amount of rounding to hide representation error.

e.g. To 6 decimal places

```
public static double round6(double d) {
    return Math.round(d * 1e6) / 1e6;
}
```

The result of `round()` and `1e6` can be represented exactly.  Additionally "[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754%3a_floating_point_in_modern_computers) requires correct rounding: that is, the rounded result is as if infinitely precise arithmetic was used to compute the value and then rounded"  The only error left is the representation error as it takes the nearest representable value.  Java's toString() assumes that when you have a double which has a nearest representable value of a shorter decimal, that is what you want to see.

e.g. The actual value for 0.1 is

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1));
```

prints

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

but when Double.toString() is passed this value, it determines that 0.1 would be converted to this double and so this is what it should be displayed.

BTW In Java 6 there is a bug where it doesn't use the minimum number of digits.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    System.out.print(i / 1000.0 + " ");
```

in Java 6 prints

```
0.0010 0.0020 0.0030 0.0040 0.0050 0.0060 0.0070 0.0080 0.0090
```

and in Java 7 prints

```
0.001 0.002 0.003 0.004 0.005 0.006 0.007 0.008 0.009
```

---

I often use printf if performance is not critical and if it is, I use a custom routine to write the double to a direct ByteBuffer to a fixed precision (effectively rounding it) This is faster as it doesn't create any objects.

> I'd also like to avoid losing data in cases like when the result is 1.1234567891234567 or 1.33333333333333 in those cases the result should remain the same.

In that case, don't round the results until you need to display them.

Comment: I don't know of an example where it does. I assume this is because there is limits to how much rounding error you can get while dividing a whole number by another whole number.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau Have included a less hand wavey answer ;)

Comment: Hm, still not satisfied. Why not use a formatting function if formatting is what you want?

Comment: @TobiasRitzau I agree, but the OP stated `not using printf` for some reason.

Comment: Fair, but there are other formatting options if you for some reason do not like the printf familiy, e.g. DecimalFormat. I guess what I wonder is why the OP doesn't want to use a formatter.

Comment: I am just guessing the OP doesn't want to use formatters because he didn't reply when asked why the OP doesn't want to use `printf` Perhaps he is using a JSon library or some output where he cannot control the conversion of double to String.

Comment: We can go on and on, I understand your point, but still think that in virtually all scenarios there is a better way :)

Answer (score 1):

Format using for example `System.out.printf("%.6f", myFloat)`.

Comment: @aviran Why don't you want to use printf? btw +1

Comment: `String.format()` takes the same arguments and gives you a `String`there are loads of other similar formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid losing decimals, use BigDecimal instead of float. Slower but more accurate .

Comment: How would BigDecimal work with functions like sin/cos/log/ln ?
Its not about calculacting accurately, i can live with the result 1.9999 but when I print it back, I want it to be 2.0, any suggestions?